# QGIS - Save not working after copy-paste between layers

Tags: qgis, layers, copy

I am trying to copy points from one layer to another in QGIS, both shapefiles, both with the same schema, both point files, both with the same Coordinate Reference System. The shapefile was originally created from a .KML

They appear to paste, including with the right attributes but when I go to save - I get the following error.

> Provider errors:
>
> - OGR error creating feature -43: Attempt to write non-point (MULTIPOINT) geometry to point shapefile.

Comment: Which version of QGIS? There was a bug with QGIS in 2.6 that led to problems with saving, with QGIS thinking all POINTs were MULTIPOINTs. Fixed in 2.6.1, apparently.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like there is geometry mismatch between POINT and MULTIPOINT.

The type of GEOMETRY that the layer is storing can be seen in that layers Properties window on the Metadata tab.

You can try converting either layer to a POINT or MULTIPOINT (depending on your requirements) using the `Vector > Geometry Tools > Multipart to Singleparts... or Singleparts to Multipart...` tools.

[image: QGIS Singlepart <> Multipart tools in menu]